# MySQL query doesn't work as it should

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having this query

```
SELECT `version` FROM filescontent WHERE `fileID`=(SELECT `fileID` FROM files WHERE `fileName`= 'file1.jpg') ORDER BY `fileID` DESC LIMIT 1
```

The problem is that it doesn't order the result descending. The result is the first one found in the database which is '1'.

Comment: If you are using 2 tables,  you have to link them

Comment: Which might be because you have "LIMIT 1" in your query, which only does its job and limits the result to one row

Comment: I need to limit it, because at ID 1 i have version 1, 2, 3 and I have to get the third version of ID1

Comment: Use `LAST(version)` then to have the last record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because you are using the LIMIT 1. Hence with 1 record how can you expect it to be in descending.

You can try to remove the LIMIT 1 and then check

```
SELECT `version` FROM filescontent 
WHERE `fileID`=(SELECT `fileID` FROM files WHERE `fileName`= 'file1.jpg') 
ORDER BY `fileID` DESC
```

Also as Hearner has suggested you can try to link  the table using JOIN like this:

```
SELECT `version` 
FROM filescontent join files using(fileID)
WHERE `fileName`= 'file1.jpg' 
ORDER BY `fileID` DESC
```

**EDIT:**

```
SELECT version FROM filescontent 
WHERE fileID=(SELECT fileID FROM files 
              WHERE fileName= 'file1.jpg') 
ORDER BY version DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I need to limit it, because at ID 1 i have version 1, 2, 3 and I have to select the third version of ID1

Answer (score 1):

use below query-

```
SELECT version 
FROM filescontent 
WHERE fileID=
(
SELECT fileID 
FROM files WHERE fileName= file1.jpg
) 
ORDER BY version DESC LIMIT 1
```

Even better query will be-

```
SELECT `version` 
FROM filescontent fc join files fl on fl.fileid=fc.fileid
WHERE `fileName`= 'file1.jpg' 
ORDER BY `version` DESC limit 1;
```

Comment: these are table aliases..you can use table name also..but aliases will help to avoid to repeat long names again and again....